# Set an application in a default intent-app

Tags: android, android-intent

I write my own player in android but in some part of the application, I need to let the users, to pick their own video player. For example, when user clicking on a video, inside my application, I need to show an Intent to pop-up and allow the user to choose it favorite video player, of course, next to my video player.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending.html#AppChooser

Comment: @SimonMarquis Thanks, My question is how to show my player in pop up ( intent chooser)?

Comment: You must register an intent-filter to catch such media file format: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

Comment: @SimonMarquis many thanks, it's guide me in right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to setup proper intent-filter for your activity. It should look like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="video/*" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible intent just pop-up in my application? I mean other application can't that play video can't see this in their pop-up?

Comment: @Amir, pls clear, what is not understood for you, or what you want to achieve.